# find a CDF for a liner transformation for indipendent random variable

Tags: probability-distributions

given that $X_1 \sim U[-2,1]. X_2=0.5e^{-|t|}, -\infty<t<\infty$.
find $F_Y$ if:

$$   Y =
\begin{cases}
X_2,  & \text{$X_1<-1$} \\
X_1, & \text{$-1 \le X_1<0$}  \\ 3, & \text{$0 \le X_1$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

I have problem solving for $-1\le X_1<0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Recall that $F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]$. So according to your definition, you want to find  $\mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]$ for $y \in [-1,0]$. How do you do that?

**EDIT**

In response to the comment below. Note that if $y \in [-1,0]$,
$$
F_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^y f_Y(z) dz
       = \int_{-\infty}^{-1} f_Y(z) dz + \int_{-1}^{y} f_Y(z) dz
       = F_{X_2}(-1) + \left( F_{X_1}(y) - F_{X_1}(-1) \right).
$$

Comment: well, I say that it'll be $F_{X1}(t)-F_{X1}(-1) + F_Y(-1)$. but that ain't the correct answer.

Comment: @user107761 note the edit. $F_Y(-1)$ can be simplified, it is really $F_{X_2}(-1)$, and now you just plug in, since you know both $F_{X_1}$ and $F_{X_2}$.